# Neural Nets: computing weight deltas is a bottleneck

Tags: neural-network

After profiling my Neural Nets' code I've realized that the method, which computes the weight changes for each arc in the network (`-rate*gradient + momentum*previous_delta - decay*rate*weight`), already given the gradient, is the bottleneck (55% inclusive samples).

Is there any trick to compute these values in a efficient manner?

Comment: You should include the code, bottlenecks are generally implementation not idea - related

Comment: When you say "55% inclusive samples" what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behaviour. I am assuming that you are using an iterative process to solve the weights at each evolution step (such as backpropagation?). If the number of neurons is large and the training (back-testing) algorithm is short, then it is normal that weight mutation such as this will consume a larger fraction of compute time during training of the neural network.

Did you get this result using a simple XOR problem or similar? If so, you will probably find that if you start to solve more complex problems (such as pattern detection in multidimensional arrays, image processing, etc.) that those functions will begin to consume an insignificant fraction of compute time.

If you are profiling, I would suggest you profile with a problem that is closer to the purpose for which the neural network is designed (I am guessing you didn't design it to solve XOR or play tic tac toe) and you will probably find that optimising code such as `-rate*gradient + momentum*previous_delta - decay*rate*weight` is more or less a waste of time, at least this is my experience.

If you *do* find that this code is compute-intensive in real-world applications then I would suggest trying to reduce the number of times this line of code is executed via structural changes. Neural network optimization is a rich field and I can't possibly give you useful advise from such a broad question, but I will say that if your program is unusually slow, you're unlikely to see significant improvements by tinkering at such low-level code. I will however suggest the following from my own experience:

1. Consider parallelisation. Many search algorithms such as those implemented in back-propagation techniques are amenable to parallel attempts to improve convergence. As weight-adjustments are identical in terms of computation demand for a given network, think `static` loops in [Open MP](http://openmp.org/wp/).
2. Modify the convergence criterion (the critical convergence rate before you stop adjustments of weights) to perform less of these calculations
3. Consider an alternative to deterministic solutions such as back-propagations, which are slightly more prone to local optimisation anyway. Consider **gaussian mutation** (All things being equal gaussian mutation will 1) reduce time spent on mutation relative to backtesting 2) increase convergence time and 3) be less prone to getting caught in local minima of the error search space)

Please note that this is a non-technical answer to what I have interpreted as a non-technical question.

Comment: Yes, you are right - this was non-technical question: I didn't want to include the code since it would be too large to explain the problem. And my implementation is not suited for any specific problem: it is more like a package, which might be applied to any kind of problem. But I do agree with your answer - thank you!